# Previous day date excluding weekend

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create an SQL query in TOAD that retrieves the data from an Oracle DB.
What it should do is retrieve all data from previous workday back to one week, but it should exclude Saturday and Sunday.
So far I am created the query below. In this format it returns me a "Missing keyword" error message. TOAD highlights my first "Between" operator.
I have the idea that I am nearly there. Who can give me the final push into the right direction.

Thanks.

```
Select orderkey, actualshipdate
from orders
Case to_char(sysdate, 'DAY')
When 'MONDAY'
then to_char(actualshipdate,'YYYYMMDD') between to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD') -11 and  to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD')-3
else to_char(actualshipdate,'YYYYMMDD') between to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD') -8 and  to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD')-1
end
order by actualshipdate asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description (and replacing the awful to_char of the dates):

```
select orderkey, actualshipdate
from orders
where 1=1
and actualshipdate between trunc(sysdate) - 8 
                     and trunc(sysdate)-(1/86400) -- midnight last night minus 1 second
and to_char(actualshipdate, 'D') not in (6,7) -- 6: Sat, 7: Sun
```

Comment: Thanks. That does the trick. However it shows me the data of sysdate as well. Is there a way to have that excluded too?

Comment: I doubt this query is working. `to_char(actualshipdate, 'DAY')` returns `'SATURDAY '`, resp. `'SUNDAY   '` - none of them will match, note they are padded with blanks. Also it presumes your current `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` is ENGLISH or similar.

Comment: Correct. Just checked the query provided by JohnHC again. And it shows the data of Saturday and Sunday as well. I overlooked them as it were so only 6 lines. What else can be done to have the weekend days excluded?

Comment: @MartijnDrohm Update made

Comment: Thanks. Now it looks perfect after some little personal adjustments. Only "not in (6,7)" had to be "not in (7,1)"